# Callback issue. Function not firing

Tags: jquery, callback

```
$("a.open").click(function () {
    $(".overlay").fadeIn(650, 'easeOutQuad', function () {
        $(".pageContainer").load(function () {
            $(this).delay(100).fadeIn(850, 'easeOutQuad');
        });
    });
});
```

I have a page that I need to display when it has fully loaded, the overlay fades in perfectly as needed, but the pageContainer that is display:none does not.

It was working perfectly when I had $(".pageContainer").delay(100).fadeIn(850,'easeOutQuad');
but I need to make sure the page is loaded before it fades in.
Can anybody see a glaring mistake and be kind enough to help me.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Do you have any errors in your console?

Comment: Error:syntax error, unrecognised expression: . jquery-1.8.3.min.js

Comment: The .load([EventObject]) binds a handler to the loaded-event. Why do you do that at the moment a fadeIn is finished? If the pageContainer-object is finsihed loading prior to the fadein finished, the handler is never fired!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the window ready:

```
$("a.open").click(function () {
    $(".overlay").fadeIn(650, 'easeOutQuad', function () {
        $(window).ready(function () {
           $(".pageContainer").delay(100).fadeIn(850, 'easeOutQuad');
        });
    });
});
```

I assume `.pageContainer` has to show itself when its content is done? I'm missing the part that is placing the content in the actual element, so I find it a bit diffucult to place the `$(window).ready()`

Comment: Actually no, what happens is the black ".overlay" which acts as a base fadeIn and remains there, then the ".pageContainer" fades in over the top of that. If the a.close button is clicked then the "pageContainer" fadesOut to the black "overlay" which itself fadeout back.

Comment: Ah, I was under the assumption it needed to fade back out (as is more common). Let me check again

Comment: That actually works, although the "Error:syntax error, unrecognised expression: . jquery-1.8.3.min.js" returns in the error console when it's fired.

Comment: I dont think this code is the actual problem, this is all fairly basic. The error would suggest uou have a `$(".")` somewhere. Maybe somewhere down the road you are using an variable in the selector without value?

Comment: I have just scanned my js document and your absolutely right, there was a $(".") nestled at the bottom that I had stripped down ready to use for something else. Thank you Martijn.